# Is Shiva or Rudra born and is he still alive? Was he killed or merged with supreme brahman at any point of time?

Tags: shiva, vedas, scripture

Is there any references in Vedas, ithihasas and puranas or any scriptures about birth of Siva or Rudra? Also, shiva purana says that Siva also has incarnations. So are all these incarnations still alive or some of them died and merged with Siva? Also are there any instances that he died or merged with supreme Brahman.

Request to please provide references from genuine scriptures(Vedas, upanishads, ithihasas, puranas etc) as support and not some wild fantacies or speculations or allegations as answers or comments

Comment: by the way, itihasas and puranas is a same thing

Comment: Well, there is a difference. Ithihasas are Ramayana and Mahabharata. Principle Puranas are 18 in number and there are some upa puranas too.

Comment: Rudram fifth anuvaka and eleventh anuvaka talks about the eternal and all pervading nature of Lord Shiva or Rudra. Here is a link to the translation http://gloryofhinduism.blogspot.com/2011/03/english-translation-of-sri-rudram.html

Comment: @Sai That's not a very good translation of the Rudram.  Here's a better one: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv04.htm (The Rudram constitutes Prapathaka V of this Kanda of the Taittiriya Samhita of the Yajur Veda.)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan wow your translation is even better (although not perfect!)!

Comment: @Sai also see my answer below...

Comment: If you are a shaivite then you consider shiva as bramhan no question of death or life and he would be eternal in that case but as a Vaishnava and with scriptural autority shiva is a jiva who has done lot of tapasya to Shriman narayana to gain his status as trimurti, and as he is jiva and vedanta accepts the eternal nature of jiva then shiva is eternal so is the rudra if the body dies he continues to exist as a jiva.

Answer (score 13):

**Rudra is both Born and Unborn.** As I discuss in my answer [here,](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9918/who-is-rudra-deva/11638#11638)
 Rudra means who cries, who makes other cry and who removes the cry of Samsara.

There may be confusion regarding born and unborn nature of Rudra with the Smriti. However **Vedas themselves attest both Born and Unborn Rudra:**

## Unborn Rudra:

He is the ParaBrahman or self of all. He is **represented in formless Linga form** or Saguna Upasakas also call him **SadaShiva.** He is unborn and eternal. He is without beginning and end.

Vedas themselves declare this Rudra who existed before Prajapati and who caused Prajapati to do action:

> व्रात्य आसीदीयमान एव स प्रजापतिं समैरयत् ।।
> स प्रजापति: सुवर्णमात्मन्नपश्यत्तत्प्राजनयत् ।।
> तदेकमभवत्तल्ललाममभवत्तन्महदभवत्तज्जेष्ठमभवत्तद्ब्रह्माभवत्तत्तपोऽभवत्तत्सत्यमभवत्तेन प्राजायत ।।
> सोऽवर्धत स महानभवत्स **महादेवोऽभवत्** ।।
> स देवानामीशां पर्यैत्स **ईशानोऽभवत्** ।।
> स एकव्रात्योऽभवत्स धनुरादत्त तदेवेन्द्रधनुः ।।
> **नीलमस्योदरं लोहितं** पृष्ठम् ।।
> नीलेनैवाप्रियं भ्रातृव्यं प्रोर्णोति लोहितेन द्विषन्तं विध्यतीति  ब्रह्मवादिनो वदन्ति ।।  [**Atharva Veda 15:1**]
>  
> **There was Vratya . He roused Prajapati to action.** Prajapati beheld gold in himself and engendered it. That became unique, that became distinguished, that became great, that became excellent, that became Brahman, that became Tapas, that became Truth: **through that he (Vratya) was born.** He grew, he became great, **he became Mahadeva.** He gained the lordship of the Gods. **He became Ishana.** He became Eka Vratya. He held a bow, even that Bow of Indra. His belly is dark-blue, his back is red (**Nila Lohita**). With dark-blue he envelops a detested rival, with red he pierces the man who hates him: so the knowers of Brahman say.

As clearly evident from above Shruti passage, the one who caused Prajapati [Brahma] to action is the same who was born from him and was known by the name of Mahadeva, Ishana, Nilalohita, etc.. ie. He himself was the cause of his birth and he was controlling Prajapati himself before his birth itself ie. He is unborn. So, anyone who think Shiva is only son of Brahma directly contradict with this Shruti passage. Thus they are wrong. That's why Svetasvatara Upanishad declare:

> यो देवानां प्रभवश्रोच्वश्रच्  विश्वाधिपो रुद्रो महर्षि ।
> हिरण्यगर्भं जनयामानस पूर्वं स नो बुद्धया शुभया संयुनक्तु।।
>  
> He, the **omniscient Rudra,** the creator of the gods and the bestower of their powers, the support of the universe, **He who, in the beginning, gave birth to Hiranyagarbha**−may He endow us with clear intellect!

He is that SadaShiva who is the cause of all causes. He himself is in the form of Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh:
For eg  He himself became Vishnu:

> स यद्ध्रुवां दिशमनु व्यचलद्विष्णुर्भूत्वानुव्य चलद्विराजमन्नादिं कृत्वा ।। विराजान्नाद्यान्नमत्ति य एवं वेद।। [**Atharvaveda 15.14**]
>  
> He (Vratya/ Mahadeva/ Ishana ), when he went away to the stedfast region, went away **having become Vishnu** and having made Virāj an eater of food”.

That's why SriRudram of YajurVeda declares:

> **नमो गिरिशाय च शिपिविष्टाय च मेढुष्टमाय च**
> Salutations to him who is in the form of Girisha (Shiva), Sipivishta (Vishnu) and Medhustama (Brahma).

This is also illustrated in Smriti passages like:
For eg. Mahabharat Anushasana Parva chapter 14 states:

> योऽसृजद्दक्षिणादङ्गाद्बर्ह्मणं लोकसंभवम् ।
> वामपाश्र्वातथा विष्णु लोकरक्षार्थमीश्वर ।।
> युगान्ते चैव संप्राप्ते रुद्रमङ्गात्सृजत्प्रभु ।। 
>
> You create **Brahma from Right side** and make the creation of world possible. **From the Left side you emerge as Vishnu** for protection of entire world. You **create Rudra** for the end of the world from your body.

Also Srimad Bhagvatam 8.7.23 states the same thing:

> गुणमय्या स्वशक्तयास्य सर्गस्थित्यत्ययान्विभो ।
> धत्से यदा स्वद्धग्भूमन्ब्रह्मविष्णुशिवाभिधाम् ।।
>  
> O Lord [**SadaShiva**], you are self-effulgent and supreme. You create this material world by your personal energy, and **you assume the names Brahmā, Viṣhṇu and Maheśvara when you act in creation, maintenance and annihilation.**

Padma Purana also states the same thing in Patala Khanda chapter 108:

> य एकः शाश्वतोदेवोब्रह्मवंद्यः सदाशिवः ।
> त्रिलोचनो गुणाधारोगुणातीतोऽक्षरोव्ययः ।।
> पृथक्कृत्वात्मनस्तातत्रस्थानंविभयज्यच ।
> दक्षिणांगेसृजत्पुरंब्रह्माणंवामतोहरिम् ।।
> पृष्ठदेशोमहेशानंत्रीन्पुत्रानसृजद्विभुः ।
> जातमात्रास्त्रयोदेवाब्रह्मविष्णुमहेश्वराः।।
>  
> He who is **that eternal god SadaShiva,** who is saluted by Brahma, who has three eyes, who is the prop of virtues, who is beyond qualities, who is unchangeable and immutable. O dear one, having divided himself and the region there, **he created on his right side the son, viz. Brahma and Hari from his left side. At the back side he created Mahesh;** thus the mighty one created three sons. As soon as they were born they became the three gods—Brahma, Vishnu and Maheswara.

**Thus the Unborn SadaShiva who is the cause of all causes and who is not son of Brahma but he himself is the Generator of Brahma is attested in both Shruti and Smriti.**

But this SadaShiva is also called by the name Rudra in Vedas. There are also Born Rudras described in Vedas. So, one has to look the context to know whether Born Rudra or Unborn Rudra (SadaShiva) is described.

SadaShiva is described of having 5 heads. His five heads are

> Sadyojata, Vamadeva, Aghora, Tatpurush, Ishana.

These 5 heads are described in Taittariya Aranyaka of YajurVeda from 10.17 to 10.21. The Upper facing head Ishana is the Ishwara of the world at all times. Hence, Taittariya Aranyaka of YajurVeda [10.21] declares:

> ईशान सर्वविद्यानां ईश्वर सर्वभूतानां ब्रह्माधिपति ब्रह्मणोधिपति ब्रह्मा शिवो मे अस्तु सदाशिवोम् ।।
>  
> May the Supreme Ishana who is the ruler of all knowledge, controller of all created beings, the preserver of the Vedas and the one overlord of Hiranyagarbha, be benign to me. **I am the SadaShiva described thus and denoted by Pranava.**

**Srimad Bhagvatam** also describes [form of SadaShiva](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/7/29) as:

> मुखानि पञ्चोपनिषदस्यवेश यैस्त्रिंशदष्टोत्तरमन्त्रवर्ग ।
> यतच्छिवाख्यं परमात्मतत्त्वं देव स्वयंज्योतिरवास्थितिस्ते।।
>  
> O lord, the five important Vedic mantras are represented by **your five faces,** from which the thirty-eight most celebrated Vedic mantras have been generated. Your Lordship, being celebrated as Lord Śhiva, is self-illuminated. **You are directly situated as the supreme truth, known as Paramātmā.**

Thus, SadaShiva or Linga form Parameshwara is the cause of all causes. He is the Unborn Rudra described in Svetasvatara Upanishad and other Shruti passages like:

> देवानां हृदयभ्यो। [YajurVeda SriRudram]
> who is on the heart of Devas (as their self).
>  
> भवस्य हेत्यै जगताम् पतये नमः । [Sri Rudram]
> Salutations to him who being the cause is the Lord of the Universe. 
>  
>  मृत्युर्मुक्षिय मामृतात् ।। [RigVeda 7.59.12] who Gives moksha and Immortality. 
>  
>  नमः सोमाय च रुद्राय च [SriRudram YajurVeda] Salutation to him who is with Uma and who destroys the misery of Samsara. 
>  
>  एको हि रुद्रो न द्वितियाय [Svetasvatara Upa.] Rudra is truly one and only one without second. 
>  
>  त्वं ज्ञात्वामृता भवन्ती । [Svetasvatara Upa.] knowing you one becomes Immortal.

Thus SadaShiva is the Unborn and eternal Rudra who is the cause of all causes.. Shankara who is sitting in Kailash Parvata with Parvati is just physical manifestation/incarnation of SadaShiva.

## Born Rudra:

There are various types of born Rudras as I discuss in my [answer here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9918/who-is-rudra-deva/11638#11638) Vedas themselves attest born Rudras also. The story of **Ashtamurti manifestation** of Rudras is described in detail in Kaushtiki Brahmana and Satapatha Brahmana. He cried just after he was born. That's why Brahma named him Rudra (rud=cry) as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe41/sbe4130.htm) of Satapatha Brahmana.

> He said to him, 'Thou art Rudra' And because he gave him that name, Agni became suchlike (or, that form), for Rudra is Agni: because he cried (rud) therefore he is Rudra. He said, 'Surely, I am mightier than that: give me yet a name!'

Brahma goes on naming his 8 forms as:

> **Rudra, Bhava, Sarva, Ugra, Bhima, Pasupati, Mahadeva, Ishana**

There are also Ekadash Rudras who are incarnation of Lord Shiva:
They Rule on Prana and Mind of Body as described in Brihadaranyaka Upanishad:

> कतमे रुद्रा इतिः दशेमे पुरुषे प्राणाः आत्मैकादशः ते यदास्माच्छरीरान्मर्त्यादुत्क्रामन्त्यथ रोदयन्ति, तद्यद्रोदयन्ति तस्माद्रुद्रा इति ।।
>
> ‘Which are the Rudras ?’ ‘The **ten pranas** in the human body, with the **mind as the eleventh.** When they depart from this mortal body, they make one’s relatives weep. Because they then make them weep, therefore they are called Rudras.’

Rudras are given birth by other also for eg:
Srimad Bhagvatam 6.6 states:

> 17-18. **Sarupa, the wife of Bhuta, gave birth to the ten million Rudras,** of whom the eleven principle Rudras were Raivata, Aja, Bhava, Bhima, Vama, Ugra, Vrsakapi, Ajaikapat, Ahirbradhna, Bahurupa 
> and Mahan. Their associates, the ghosts and goblins, who are very fearful, were born of the other wife of Bhuta.

Rudras are also born from Narayana also:
Narayana Upanishad says: "Narayana Rudro Jayet" or Rudra was born from Narayana.
In Mahabharat Shanti Parva chapter 342 also Krishna says:

> He should be known as one that has sprung from my wrath.

Srimad Bhagvatam 5.25.3 also tells Rudras manifesting from wrath of Sesha Naag:

> At the time of devastation, when Lord Anantadeva desires to destroy the entire creation, He becomes slightly angry. Then from between His two eyebrows appears three-eyed Rudra, carrying a trident. This 
> Rudra, who is known as Sankarsana, is the embodiment of the eleven Rudras, or incarnations of Lord Siva. He appears in order to devastate the entire creation.

Thus as we see from above **Rudras get birth from Brahma, Vishnu, Sarupa, Shiva, Sesha, etc.. in different conditions.** Also the name of Ekadash Rudras change frequently in Puranas due to KalpaBheda.

### Incarnations of Lord Shiva:

There are various incarnations of Lord Shiva the most famous being Ashtamurti Manifestation. He manifest as son of Brahma in 8 different forms and enters the creation as:

> Rudra, Bhava, Sarva, Ugra, Bhima, Pasupati, Mahadeva, Ishana

Ekadash Rudras are also his incarnations. Their name frequently changes in Puranas due to KalpaBheda.

Besides Ashtamurti incarnation and Ekadash Rudra incarnation there are also other incarnations in various Kalpas and Mahayugas:

[This excerpt](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12959/3/Chapter1_1070-1148p.pdf) from ShatRudra Samhita of Shiva Purana describes incarnation in various Kalpas like:

> Sadyojata incarnation in Svetalohita Kalpa. Vamadeva incarnation in Rakta Kalpa. Aghora incarnation in Pitavasas Kalpa. Ishana incarnation in Visvarupa Kalpa.

The [same excerpt](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12959/3/Chapter1_1070-1148p.pdf) in Chapter 5 also lists various incarnation taking place in various Mahayugas. These incarnations were named as:

> Bali, Gautama, Vedasira, Gokarna, Guhavasin, Sikhandin, Jati, Malin, Doruka, Bhava, Halayudha, Sveta, Sulin, Mundisvara, Sahisnu, Somasarma, Lakulin.

#### Death of Rudra:

There are not any scripture which mention Rudras died at particular time. Personally I think at the end of Kalpa or Mahakalpa they merge back to Lord Shiva.

Also there are also not any scripture which state Shiva/Rudra is a title and one can achieve this position by doing this and this.

Comment: In the Lalita Saubhagya Vaibhavam it is said "Brahma Vishnu Shiva Indradi **Pada Vishranana** Kshama" - One who is an expert in granting the positions of Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva and Indra. (Even though I don't know about authenticity since there is a scripture saying so maybe you should remove the last line.)

Comment: Very comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Tezz - Very informative answer. By the way , can you pls. give me some links / Name of the books where I could know more about "RudraAvatra" story. Thanks :)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks!... Shiva Purana and Linga Purana are the one where Rudravtars are described in details... There is also a link in my answer:... http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12959/3/Chapter1_1070-1148p.pdf   ......You can search and download and read Shiva and Linga Purana also....

Comment: @Tezz -Ok , I will go through that :)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Definitely want to know the reactions of Vaishnavas on that verse of Padma Purana because they believe that any Purana which glorifies Shiva is Tamasa, so that in turn will make Padma Purana Tamasa! But I think they will say that verse is interpolation.

Comment: The above verses confirm that Sadashiva has a specific form so I think he is same as Maha Shambhu mentioned in Brahmanda Purana who is responsible for creation after Maha Pralaya(end of Brahma's 100 years). I read in the introduction of Mahanirvana tantra that Para Shiva is superior to Sadashiva so maybe Para Shiva is Nirguna Brahman of Advaita.

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupria I haven't read Mahanirvana Tantra...Para Shiva may represent Nirguna Brahman as  Para means beyond... but yes SadaShiva has specific five headed form...Samba with Sadashiva can convert into form of Nirguna Linga form being in ArdhaNarishwara form.. as Taittariya Aranyaka states "Ritam Satyam Param Brahman Purush Krishnapingala".. ie.. ParaBrahman is in ArdhaNarishwara form... By the way... Pashupatinath ShivaLinga of Nepal has five heads...Heads are formed itself in Linga....

Comment: The moment you say Linga, it is not nirguna. The nirguna Brahman of even Advaita is not Parvati pati or sati pati..Don't parrot some verses from Shiva puarana, Linga purana etc.. None of the reasoning by you is given by even ancient advaitins..It is called Siva because it is auspicious. It has got nothing to do with Parvati pati. Narayana is the ultimate auspiciousness..Hence, Adi Shankaracharya completely accepts that Naarayana is the ultimate auspiciousness i.e the Ultimate Siva. Genuine Advaita is different and has got nothing to do with Parvati Pati or Shaivism or Shaktam.

Comment: @Krishna 1) Linga is definitely not nirguna. It is connection between Saguna and Nirguna 2) For your Kind information I haven't used any verses from Shiva and Linga Purana (as I preassume as a Vaishnava you consider those Puranas as Tamasic) 3) It has definitely to do with Parvati Pati... as Taittariya Aranyaka clearly states Ambikapataye Umapataye Pasupataye 4) I have nothing to do with what AdiShankara accepts. Accepting someone as supreme is based on Prakriti Swabhava of person

Comment: @Krishna 5) yes, genuine Advaita is different. But people nowadays are illustrating Shiva as Supreme in Advaita. It is wrong. In Advaita only Nirguna Brahman is supreme. At Paramarthika Satya level Ishwara doesn't exist at all. So, there is no meaning calling personal God as Supreme in Advaita. But people nowadays are misinterpreting it... and as per my understanding AdiShankara treats name of Gods as attributes...

Comment: @Tezz - This is where the problem arises. Ambika doesn't mean parvati alone. Uma is not Parvati alone. Please read Adi Shankaracharya's  commentary on Nrisimha Tapani upanishad for which the famous shavaite Swami Vidyaranya has written a sub commentary. Adi Shankaracharya clearly says that Uma refers to Goddess Lakshmi and hence Uma pati means only Sriyahpati. I am not saying this. this meaning is given by Adi Shankaracharya. So, Uma means fame and prosperity (yashas). Ambika means mother. So, it doesn't refer to Parvati alone. you are giving the shavaite and shaktam versions.

Comment: @Krishna 1) It is true every name in Sanskrit is just an attribute. So, Uma can refer Godesses Lakshmi. 2) However if you look it in context it comes in the passage of Rudra along with names like Mahadeva, Ishana, etc.. 3) The same line contains the name Pasupati. Now you can't tell Pasupati here means Vishnu. Even in the Vishnu Sahasranam Pashupati name isn't used. Pashupati is reserve name of Shiva. So, it is definitely referring Shiva. 4) I'm free to intrepret it in Shakta and Shaivite way. It isn't necessary that I must intrepret in Vaishnava way.. that too ridiculous intrepretation..

Comment: @Krishna 5) Again I have nothing to do with how Adi Shankara intreprets. 6) Also Vaishnavas tell that Padma Purana tells AdiShankara is a deceiver. So,(if AdiShankara intrepreted that way) maybe AdiShankara intrepreted in that way to deceive people... Hehe

Comment: @Tezz - You can and are free to interpret it in any most ridiculous Shaiva or Shaktam versions also. Pashupati is well explained and doesn't refer to Parvati Pati alone. Well, if you look somewhere else, it means Chaturmukha Brahma created Siva and parvati pati as per context in Other Vedic passages....All these names occur there too.

Comment: @Krishna 1) yes, it's true Brahma created Rudra.. It's well explained in Satapatha Brahmana. Names like Pasupati, Ishana, Mahadeva etc... exist there.... But it is just AshtaMurti manifestation.... 2) If you look the first verse of that chapter of Satapatha Brahmana where Brahma creates Rudra then it tells **"Verily Prajapati Alone was there. He self existed."** So, it clearly establishes Brahma as the Supreme Brahman. It also means Prajapati alone is the Supreme Brahman. So it means that Puranas, Itihasas which claim Brahma created by Vishnu are wrong....

Comment: @Tezz - Yes, but that Para Brahman is not Parvati Pati is very clear fro those verses.

Comment: @Krishna 1) It doesn't definitely establishes that ParaBrahman is Parvati Pati as it is just AshtaMurti manifestation. Another Ekadash Rudra manifestation is stated in Brih. Upa. 2) Well, we will not agree on this matter anyway as you consider Shiva as Jeeva and title 3) I consider both Shiva and Vishnu as Supreme. For me there is no problem as I don't believe in concept of Antaryami. For me Shiva and Vishnu are like a glass of milk is kept in table and a person seeing from west is claiming it to be Shiva and seeing from east is claiming it to be Vishnu...

Comment: @Krishna 4) I'm talking with you in Shaivite perspective because you are talking with me in Vaishnava perspective. I also consider Lord Vishnu as Supreme. You can see my answers like           http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12032/why-ravana-of-ramayana-is-worshipped-like-god-and-also-considered-as-a-demon/12033# http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/where-does-the-linga-purana-declare-vishnu-to-be-the-supreme-soul/13933#1393312033

Comment: @Tezz- SadaShiva just means ultimate Auspiciousness not identified with Parvati Pati alone. Vishnu Sahasranama says the same," mangala nancha mangalam". For Vaishnavas, Parvati Pati is Jeevathma only, who many times acts as great Jnani and Guru. For that matter every thing else is Jeevathma tattva except Lord Narayana, who alone is paramatma.   Anyway, you say you wouldn't agree with even Adi Shankaracharya himself and his commentaries and again talk in same mold as many of those ignoramuses. Anyway, I leave it there. It was nice discussing, after a long hiatus..

Comment: @Krishna well, it's a beauty of Hinduism that one can intrepret a single thing in Various way... However SadaShiva also means Umapati and it is confirmed by S.B. 8.17.19 and those mantras of Taittariya Aranyaka are also for Lord Shiva again confirmed in S.B. 8.17.27.... but anyway you can intrepret them differently... Regarding position of Shiva in Vaishnavism... at least Gaudiya consider 2 Shivas one Sada Shiva who is direct incarnation of Krishna/Vishnu and another Shiva who is son of Brahma... in that case SadaShiva is not Jeevatma... he is Nitya Suri...

Comment: @Krishna also SriVaishnava Acharyas talk about existence of SadShiva who has separate existence then Shiva who is son of Brahma... in that case SadaShiva acts as Nitya Suri not Jeevatma... I don't know which sect of Vaishnavism do you belong to... but I preassume you belong to Sri Vaishnavism.... Anyway it was a nice discussing with you...

Comment: @Tezz - When I said Every thing is Jeevathma, what my understanding is that which is controlled, supported by Paramatma and dependent on Paramatma. Jeevathma s are three types Nitya, Muktas and baddha.  nitya Suris although not in the same class as Muktas or baddhas are also Jeevathmas in general, is my understanding. May be you are right when you say SriVaishnava acharyas regard SadaShiva as Nitya suri. I am not aware of it. Infact, there are many Nitya suriss who are elephant headed also. Unfortunately people misconstrue them to be Vinayaka or Ganesha, the son of  Parvati and Lord Siva

Comment: @Krishna well I don't know about SriVaishnava... but Gaudiyas do not consider SadaShiva as Jeeva tatwa... In Gaudiya there are 3 Tatwas Vishnu tatwa, Shiva tatwa and Jeeva tatwa... but anyways Sri Vaishnava acharya do recognise SadaShiva... you can read this question .. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10730/what-scriptures-describe-sadashiva-carrying-vishnu-in-vishnus-abode-of-paramapa

Comment: @Krishna and yes you are right... Nitya Suri which are elephant headed in Parampadam of ParaVasudeva isn't Ganesha... They are Vishvaksena and his attendents...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Not just Samhāra Rudra, Brahmā and Nārāyana too undergo utpatti and kshaya (aka creation and destruction) and merge with prakriti in the course of prākrita pralaya

### Kurma Purāna, Purva Bhāga, Chapter 5

[image]

Even though the Trinity is subject to creation and lapse, the eternal, all-pervading, independent Kāla,  Mahesvara who transcends the three remains the same.

[image]

Although there are many Chaturmukha Brahma-s, Rudras and Narayanas, there is only one Maheshwara called Kaala.

Padma Purana too distinguishes between the born Rudra(who is subject to birth, old age. etc.) and the unborn Shiva who is the supreme lord.

### Padma Purana Srishti Khanda Chapter 43

> 172-173. O great Mountain, being composed, (give) a thought to what I
> said. Her (Parvati's) husband is not born—this is what I said truly. **O Himālaya,
> that Mahādeva (i.e. Śiva) is unborn, and is the origin of the past,
> future and present. He is the protector, ruler, benefactor and the
> highest lord.**
>
> **O Mountain, Brahmā, Rudra, Indra, sages—all of them oppressed by being subjected to conception, birth and old age, are his toys**.