# Why is Lord Shiva called indivisible, Ram & Ravan in Shivaay Trailer?

Tags: shiva

I recently watched [Shivaay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poLjq0u4_5A&ab_channel=AjayDevgn) trailer thus asking few question on this.
1) In this trailer why Lord Shiva is called **Indivisible**. I know its literal meaning but what it means mythologically.
2) Why is Shiva called **Mahaekaki** i.e. loneliest of all?
3) Why is this line said,"**Ram bhi uska, Ravaan bhi uska**"? I know Ravaan was Shiva Bakht but Ram was Vishnu avataar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all it is not necessary that a trailer would show everything fully scripture based.

It looks like Ajay Devagan doesn't consider Lord Shiva as mere Destroyer or Transformer but  he considers Lord Shiva as [Supreme Brahman](https://twitter.com/ajaydevgn/status/598525714548133893?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) (Creator, Protector and Destroyer). This is also evident from his statement

> "ना आदि ना अंत है उसका, वो सबका ना इनका उनका, वही शून्य है वही इकाय,
> जिसके भीतर बसा शिवाय।"
>
> With no beginning and no end, indivisible, equal to all, nothing and
> yet everything, Shiva is in all of us.

So, all these points can be answered from Supreme perspective of Lord Shiva.

#### 1) Indivisiblty of Lord Shiva:

In the absolute level and absolute truth is that there doesn't exist another than Shiva. The whole world we see different is just due to relative perception. It is confirmed in Svetasvatara Upanishad [3.2] as:

> एको हि रुद्रो न द्वितीयाय तस्थु-
>          र्य इमांल्लोकानीशत ईशनीभिः ।
> प्रत्यङ् जनास्तिष्ठति सञ्चुकोचान्तकाले
>          संसृज्य विश्वा भुवनानि गोपाः ॥ २॥
>
>  
> **Rudra is truly one; for the knowers of Brahman do not admit the existence of a second,** He alone rules all the worlds by His powers. He dwells as the inner Self of every living being. After having created all the worlds, He, their Protector, takes them back into Himself at the end of time.

So if there is only one. How can he be divided?

Moreover Taittariya Aranyaka of YajurVeda [10.24] states the changing world and whatever we see and perceive is simply Lord Shiva/Rudra.

> विश्वं भूतं भुवनं चित्रं बहुधा जातं जायमानं च
> यत् । सर्वो ह्येष रुद्रस्तस्मै रुद्राय नमो अस्तु ॥ १॥
>  
> **The whole universe the created beings and whatever there is manifoldly and profusely created in the past and in the present in the form of the world, all that is indeed this Rudra.** Salutations be to Rudra who is such.

So, as everything is Rudra only in both absolute and relative level and there doesn't exist second. It is obvious that he can be called Indivisible.

#### 2) Shiva as alone:

In the relative perception level Lord Shiva isn't alone, he is always with Uma. But again from absolute level, as also established from above passages as there is no second, so he would obviously be alone. It is further confirmed in Svetasvatara Upanishad [4.18] as:

> दाऽतमस्तान्न दिवा न रात्रिः
>            न सन्नचासच्छिव एव केवलः ।
> तदक्षरं तत् सवितुर्वरेण्यं
>            प्रज्ञा च तस्मात् प्रसृता पुराणी ॥ १८॥
>  
> **When there is no darkness of ignorance, there is no day or night, neither being nor non—being; Shiva alone exists.** That immutable Reality is the meaning of "That"; It is adored by the Sun. From It has proceeded the ancient wisdom.

#### 3) He is for both Rama and Ravana:

Both Rama and Ravana were devotees of Lord Shiva.

Ravana [worshiped](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14293/3500) Lord Shiva with sincere devotion at Mount Kaliasa offering his nine heads. In summer he performed tapas in panchagni (five fires), during rainy season he sat on the bare earth, and during winter he performed tapas in water. Finally when his ego was subdued, Lord Shiva granted Ravana boons.

Rama also worshiped Lord Shiva. This is what He says to Sita Devi in [Verse 19 of Yuddha Kanda - Book Of War, Chapter [Sarga] 123, Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga123/yuddha_123_frame.htm#Verse19),

> एतत् कुक्षौ समुद्रस्य स्कन्धावारनिवेशनम् || ६-१२३-१९ 
> **अत्र पूर्वं
> महादेवः प्रसादमकरोत्प्रभुः** |
>
> "See this island, located in the middle of the ocean, where my troops
> were stationed. **At this place, the lord Shiva (the supreme deity)
> formerly bestowed his grace on me."**

One among the 12 Jyotirlingas ie. Sri Rameshwaram Jyotirlinga was established by Lord Rama, as I discuss in my [answer here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14349/what-is-the-story-of-rameshwaram-jyotirlinga/14350#14350)

Comment: @The Destroyer feel fully free to edit answer as you want... also this answer may be needed to you to link it... http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12032/why-ravana-of-ramayana-is-worshipped-like-god-and-also-considered-as-a-demon/12033#12033

Answer (score 0):

All living entities, being a spirit soul, are indivisible. This is confirmed in the Bhagavad Gita:

*nainaṁ **chindanti** śastrāṇi

nainaṁ dahati pāvakaḥ

na cainaṁ kledayanty āpo

na śoṣayati mārutaḥ*

"The soul can **never be cut to pieces by any weapon**, nor burned by ﬁre, nor moistened by water, nor withered by the wind." (BG 2.23)

The  word ekaki is used in various places throughout scriptures. BG 6.30 is one such verse. It means alone. Alone means from material point of view he may be alone but he is always absorbed in trance and hence remains aloof from materialistic audience, in that sense alone. Internally he's always associating with Supreme Lord or Paramatma seeing His presence everywhere in every atom. Of course this is a higher state.

Regarding the statement - Ravana and Ram are Shiva's is misleading and incorrect.

During the time of Ramayana war, Ravana prayed to Shiva for protection, but Shiva didn't appear to protect Ravana from Rama, why? This was questioned by Parvati devi to Shiva: "Why are you not protecting your devotee Ravana while he is praying to you?" Shiva replied that Paravati devi didn't see his opponent who is Lord Rama Himself, his (Lord Shiva's) master. Hence Lord Shiva couldn't do anything. Else why he didn't give protection to Ravana against Lord Rama?

Regarding Lord Ram's worshiping Shiva:

If your father makes you sit on his lap or shoulder, does that mean you become superior to your father? Krishna lifted the footwear of his father on his head. He was chastised by his mother. Does that make them superior to Him? Krishna liked being defeated by his friends, so have they become superior? No. That's 3rd class conclusion.

No one can understand this aspect of krishna at least by gyana and karma. Only by Bhakti yoga can one understand the transcendental activities of Krishna, not by gyana. Proof?

Arjuna was not a sannyasi, not a gyani, he was a kshatriya householder and Krishna instructed Him:

[Bg 4.3](http://www.vedabase.com/bg/4/3) — "That very ancient science of the relationship with the Supreme is today told by Me to you because you are **My devotee as well as My friend** and can therefore understand the transcendental mystery of this science."

In the end Arjuna completely understood Krishna and accepted Him as Supreme not out of sentimentality but as approved by other Acharyas (as per [BG 10.12-13](http://www.vedabase.com/bg/10/12-13)).

So Krishna's qualities cannot be understood externally or merely by shastra. In Bhakti Yoga, the devotee and master are on absolute level. that is why we see Krishna accepted to become charioteer of Arjuna.

This is Vishnu tattva.

Lastly:

“[Lord Śiva addressed his wife, Durgā:] ‘O Varānanā, I chant the holy name of Rāma, Rāma, Rāma and thus enjoy this beautiful sound. This holy name of Rāmacandra is equal to one thousand holy names of Lord Viṣṇu.’

This is a verse from the Brhad-visnu-sahasranama-stotra in the Uttara-khanda of the Padma Purana (72.335).

We also see that Banasura was a devotee of Shiva. He misused his tapasya to get such a boon from Lord Shiva that Krishna had to come to rescue.

If everything is Brahman and nothing beyond, why then the Brahmavadis distinguish between chapati and processed chapati that comes from stomach (human excreta) since everything is one? Monist means no duality, everything one. So they must not distinguish between the two :P

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43811/discussion-on-answer-by-ka-why-is-lord-shiva-called-indivisible-ram-ravan).