# What is the physical appearance of Lord Rudra in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, shiva, rudra

[image]

I wanted to know more about the physical appearance of Rudra in the Vedas , Like what does Krittivāsa and Nīlagrīva actually mean?

Comment: Looks like the same as the following question? -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22294

Comment: @Rickross I have some confusion regarding the word "Kṛtti" actually meaning skin or hide? Can u clear my doubts and tell me what does "Kṛttivāsa" actually mean?

Comment: "Like what does Krittivāsa and Nīlagrīva actually mean?", How do we know what they actually mean? like do you need what commentators say.. or how Brhamanas or Puranas explain that word?..

Comment: @Tezz I know about the commentators. Both Sāyana and Bhatta Bhāskara have interpreted "Kṛttivāsa" as one having tiger skin as his attire . I wanna know if the word "Kṛtti' has been used anywhere else in the Vedas as "Hide" or "Skin".

Comment: @Tezz can you tell how the Brāhmanas explain the term "Kṛtti"?

Answer (score 3):

All names below are from Sri Rudram or Rudra Suktas:

कृत्तिवासा (Krittivasa)

> कृत्ति (Kritti) means hide or skin.
>
> वासा/वसान (Vasa) means clothes
>
> कृत्तिवासा = One who wears clothes of skin or hide

Rigveda 8.90.6 uses the word "महीव कृत्ति" in the sense of "like a hide"

नीलग्रीवा (Nilagriva)

> नील (Nila) means blue
>
> ग्रीवा (Griva) means neck
>
> नीलग्रीवा = One who has blue neck

त्र्यम्बक (Tryambaka)

> त्रि (Tri) means three
>
> अम्बक (Ambaka) means eyes
>
> त्र्यम्बक = One who has three eyes

कपर्दिन (Kapardin)

> कपर्दिन means who has matted hairs

पिनाकं-बिभ्रत् (Pinakam-bibhrat)

> पिनाकं = Pinaka bow
>
> बिभ्रत् = Carrying
>
> पिनाकं-बिभ्रत् means who carries Pinaka bow

Comment: Thanks! , the Atharvaveda Śaunaka Samhita 1.27.2 aslo has the word Pināka , The transactors have translated the word as a "Club" or "Spear"?

Comment: And why does Yāska in the Nirukta interprets the word "Kritti" as "fame" and "food". (Nirukta 5.22)