# Does the word Purusha occur in the Rig Veda other than Purusha Suktam?

Tags: rig-veda, purusha, purusha-sukta

Purusha Suktam of Rig Veda contains the word "Purusha". However, I would like to know if the word Purusha can be found in any other Sukta other than this Purusha Sukta in the Rig Veda.

Comment: A tricky question, in my view:-)  @Spark Sunshine

Comment: @srimannarayanakv yes, indeed

Comment: I have a doubt  that you're going to prove the Purusha Suktam  is an interpolation,  as the word Purusha did not occur elsewhere in Rig Veda.:-) @ Spark Sunshine

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I am a believer of divine origin of Vedas. So I don't accept anything called interpolation in Vedas.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv why you think that Purusha suktam is an interpolation?It is also Found in Yajurveda and Purusha word is there in Rig veda khilani.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda:  I am not the first person to say that.  Anyways, read my answer elsewhere. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35160/3869

Comment: @SparkSunshine You just want to know whether that word is found or not? Or if the word is found and used in the sense it is used in Purusha Sukta?

Comment: I purusha is the supreme indestructible electrical consciousness that pervades entire creation, exist beyond everything for eternity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[W. Norman Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Norman_Brown) in *[The Sources and Nature of puruṣa in the Puruṣasūkta](https://www.jstor.org/stable/593661)* says there are four other Rigvedic hymns that use the word puruṣa but in contexts very different from the Cosmic Being of the Puruṣasūkta.

> The word *puruṣa* occurs in four other hymns of the RV. Once it is used in the plural meaning "men" as contrasted with cows ([10.165.3](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10165.htm)); once it is used in the singular meaning "man" ([7.104.15](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv07104.htm)). In [10.51.8](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10051.htm) *puruṣām auṣadhīnām* "the vital element of the plants", is one of the things demanded by Agni as his portion of the sacrificial offerings; the hymn concerns Agni's well-known flight from the sacrifice and his discovery by Yama in the waters and the plants; the *puruṣa* of the plants is Agni himself who had entered them (10.51.3), now paradoxically demanded by the god. The same interpretation of *puruṣa* is probably indicated in the fourth hymn where the word occurs, the hymn to the plants ([10.97](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10097.htm)). The results here are not decisive, but the fact that *puruṣa*, where it has a specialized usage, appears in an Agni context is at least suggestive.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the word 'Purusha' is used in several places like:

> प्रयाजान्मे अनुयाजाँश्च केवलानूर्जुस्वन्तं हविषो दत्त भागम्।  
>   घृतं चापा **पुरुषं** चौषधीनामग्नेश्च दीर्घमायुरस्तु देवा।। *(RigVeda 10.51.8)* 
>  
>   prayājānme anuyājām̐śca kevalānūrjusvantaṃ haviṣo datta bhāgam।
>  
>   ghṛtaṃ cāpā **puruṣaṃ** cauṣadhīnāmagneśca dīrghamāyurastu devā।। 
>   
>   हेति: पक्षिणी न दभात्यस्मानाष्ट्रयां पदं कृणुते अग्निधाने। 
>  
>   शं नो गोभ्यश्च **पुरुषेभ्य**श्चास्तु मा नो हिंसीदिह देवा: कपोतः।। *(RigVeda 10.165.03)*
>  
>   heti: pakṣiṇī na dabhātyasmānāṣṭrayāṃ padaṃ kṛṇute agnidhāne। 
>   śaṃ no gobhyaśca **puruṣebhya**ścāstu mā no hiṃsīdiha devā: kapotaḥ।।

Comment: Good answer. You can provide translation in English also.