# How have prominent gurus shown evidence that specifically the supreme God (e.g. Brahman) exists and not just other supernatural stuff in Hinduism?

Tags: supernatural

One thing that always bothers me when the Abrahamic religions try to present evidence of their God, is that the evidence, even if the claimed experiences are fully believed, can always be explained by supernatural phenomena they believe in that is not God. For example, demons/djinn can explain literally everything experienced they claim is for God, without God. Thus adding a supreme God to the mix is completely redundant. Usually, apologists will make a completely baseless assertion that supernatural entities prove God, without reason or attempt to disprove religions that believe in the same entities without a supreme God.

Now while the supreme God is important for worship in Hinduism, whether or not he exists has almost no impact on any of the other beliefs like reincarnation, so I don't really mind as much when Hindus claim evidence for God, because it doesn't change much if it turns out to be the other stuff.

Still, the question is worth asking. What is the proof for specifically the supreme God?

Comment: Well that is one of the main differences between Buddhism and Hinduism. Buddhism makes exactly the same argument that you are making and rejects God and Soul. Hinduism especially Vedanta conjectures that God is also a supernatural entity but he is Omniscient, Omnipotent, Omnipresent, Omnibenevolent. And they prove his existence by Vedas and not logical proof. Hindus argue that Vedas are infallible, as they are Apaurusheya whatever they say is true. So if Vedas say there is Ishwara and God, then he's there. That's the argument.

Comment: Proofs in spirituality are subjective not objective. I can know something to be true but can't prove the same to others. If I have done some spiritual practice and austerities and obtain some knowledge of truth why should another person get his own proof of that truth via me? What spiritual practice or merit he has to get that proof? He has to verify it himself. There is no other way in spirituality.

Comment: @MrGreenGold Well the supreme God could just be added so people pay attention. It seems most people will give the supreme God more attention than other parts of their faith that are just as important.

Comment: @Rickross Even with spiritual practice and merit gaining a convincing experience, you could always explain it with demonic possession or an illusion created by an apsara or djinn.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa see when you say "added" you mean to imply that it was a choice. That someone made it. That would mean Vedas were written by some people in  a certain way. That's not Hinduism. The basic belief is no one wrote the Vedas, that Vedas are Apaurusheya. So nobody "added" God. It was not a choice. It was revealed in the Vedas. If you think Vedas were written by someone then its a different argument. That's not Hindu. Hindu by definition believes Vedas are Apourusheya.

Comment: @MrGreenGold There are few references in the Veda that are definiteively talking about the supreme God. Thus, the supreme God could be an interpolation or a metaphor. Everyone seems to use those excuses for far wider commented on things when it suits them anyway..

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa there are not few references. Vedas are filled with references of God. Well you can say whatever you don't like as interpolation. No body is using any excuses. Vedas clearly speak of one true God, please read Brahma Sutras especially the starting 4 sutras. Well you are confusimg Jainism or Nirishwara Purva Mimamsa with Vedanta. You are thinking like a Jain or Purva Mimamsa guy. You can choose to be that. But today's Hinduism is largely different from what you are saying.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa you ask for proof and when it's shown you say it's interpolation. If we start playing this game anyone can disprove anyone by saying oh it's a metaphor, oh it's interpolation. We can disprove anything. Like did Buddha exist? Maybe he's an interpolation, or maybe he is a metaphor. Like what?? So we use Occam's razor and use the moat obvious meaning.

Comment: @MrGreenGold To gods yes, but not the supreme God. Most of the references taken to mean the supreme God make sense if not talking about him. The Brahma Sutras are not part of the Vedas either.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa of course Brahma sutras are not Vedas, but they explain Vedas. Read it. It makes an argument from the Vedas for God.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa  Read this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48794/22253

Comment: @MrGreenGold I didn't start "playing this game." Many people believe much more referenced things are interpolation or metaphor. It's just that people tend to have an over-focus on the supreme God, so it seems more different.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa there's literally Purusha Sukta which speaks of one God. Even though some claim it's a later addition. It still is very old and is from Vedic period.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa can you tell me what's the difference between Jains and Hindus??

Comment: @MrGreenGold While a supreme God is the most obvious, Indra (as integral to the universe), scriptures, and Hinduism being much more balanced with villains and demons come to mind.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa you are confusimg demi gods with God

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa of course Brahma sutras are not Vedas, but they explain Vedas. Read it. It makes an argument from the Vedas for God