# Swayambhuva form of Shivalinga

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

Baijnath is famous for its 13th-century temple dedicated to Shiva as Vaidyanath, ‘the Lord of physicians’. The Baijnath temple has been continuously under worship ever since its construction in 1204 A.D.The Swayambhuva form of Shivalinga is enshrined in the sanctum of the temple that has five projections on each side and is surmounted with a tall curvilinear Shikhara.The famous Madurai Meenakshi temple in Madurai also has a Swayambhuva Shiva linga.It is understood that the Swayambhuva form of Shivalinga is also there in other places.What is the meaning/significance of the Swayambhuva form of Shivalinga?

Comment: Do you want importance of **Vaidyanatha** or "Swayambhuva Shiva Linga"?

Comment: You may be interested in my answer here regarding worship of Lord Shiva in Linga form: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/101/why-is-shiva-primarily-worshipped-in-a-linga-form/14214#14214

Comment: @Uday Krishna also see my answer here regarding born and unborn nature of Lord Shiva... http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8210/is-shiva-or-rudra-born-and-is-he-still-alive-was-he-killed-or-merged-with-supre/14025#14025

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swayambhu as you may know means originated on its own.They appear suddenly or mysteriously without any human efforts. Also mostly science do not have answer as to how Shiva Swayambhu has come into existence. This whole thing sounds like a majestic/divine experience and usually people who believe god tend to bow to such special mysteries.

Below are some points that may help understand the significance of Swayambhu Shivlinga:

- Swayambhu type of Shivlinga has tremendous amount of spiritual energy, and that is one common reason that these are mostly situated inside the ground.  Below picture may help understand the spiritual energy in Shiva lingam.

[image]

- The **Jyotirlinga** Shivlings have the maximum amount of intense Shiva Principle in them; [followed by the Swayambhu Shivlings](http://forumforhinduawakening.org/dharma/blog/shiva-lingam/).
- Swayambhu Shivlinga are created due to the resolve (sankalp) of Lord Shiva. The discovery of such a Shiva lingam happens when devotees get a Divine inspiration to look for it, and after the discovery its worship begins.

Hence Swayambhu are in general seems more superior to man-made idol, **psychologically**, and that is why Swayambhu has a special place/respect in Hinduism!

Comment: glad to help! I also added the ref. to the original site from where I fetched the info. I m sure you must have checked it