# Is Indra not included in twelve Adityas?

Tags: indra

As per [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/421/12304):

> अष्टउवसव ,एकादश रुद्रा ,द्वादशादित्यास् , तएकत्रिंशद् , इन्द्रश्चैवप्रजापतिश्च त्रयस्त्रिंशाविति
>
> Eight Vasus, eleven Rudras, twelve Adityas. These are thirty one,
> Indra and Prajapati make it thirty three.
>
> **— Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 3.9**

As Indra is mentioned other than 12 Adityas. So is Indra not included in twelve Adityas? Or are there 13 Adityas (12 + Indra)?

Please note that my question is not on the identity of the other two deities that fill out the 33 as it varies from list to list. Another list include the two Aśvins instead of Indra and Prajapati.

**Update**: If Indra is not included in 12 Adityas, then please provide list of 12 Adityas too. Or if Indra is included as post then does that mean there are only 32 Devas and not 33 when Purendra, the son of Aditi holds the title of Indra.

Comment: According to both srutis and smritis, there are multiple "indras" it's a **title** after all, for example the pandavas were five Indras which were cursed to become human, this also explains why there is difference in personality of sruti and smriti Indra. There is even a avatar of Lord Vishnu named indra- Indra yajna to be precise.

Comment: @YDS your question was initially lacking refrence so i edited it check if you are Ok,with it. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry it warries from place to place it. May be it is a difftrent list of 33 gods. But yes becouse vedas call indra as aditya so he is.

In the Rigveda, the Âdityas are
the seven celestial deities, sons
of Âditi,

1. Varuna
2. Mitra
3. Aryaman
4. Bhaga
5. Anśa or Aṃśa
6. Dhatri
7. **Indra**

The eighth Âditya ( Mārtanda) was rejected by Aditi, thus leaving only seven sons. In the Yajurveda (Taittirīya Samhita), their number is given as eight,
and the last one is believed to be Vivasvān . Hymn LXXII of the Rig Veda, Book 10, also confirms that there are nine Adityas, the eighth one being Mārtanda, who is later revived as Vivasvān.

> 8 Eight are the Sons of Adid who from her body sprang to life. With seven she went to meet the Gods she cast Martanda far away.
>
> 9 So with her Seven Sons Aditi went forth to meet the earlier age. She brought Martanda thitherward to spring to life and die again.
>
> **— Hymn LXXII of the Rig Veda, Book 10**

All other puranas in post-vedic mention about 33 gods among whom 12 are adityas and indra is one of them.

In the [Vishnu Purana chapter 50](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp050.htm), the names of 12 Adityas are given as:

1. Vishnu (The head of all the Adityas)
2. Aryaman
3. **Indra**
4. Tvashtha
5. Varuna
6. Dhata
7. Bhaga
8. Parjanya
9. Vivasvan
10. Amshuman
11. Mitra
12. Push

According to the [Linga Purana](http://www.astrojyoti.com/lingapurana-6.htm) , the Adityas are:

1. Vishnu
2. Aryaman
3. **Indra** (The head of Ādityas)
4. Tvaṣṭṛ
5. Varuṇa
6. Dhata
7. Bhaga
8. Savitṛ
9. Vivasvat
10. Amshuman
11. Mitra
12. Pūṣan

From  Shatapatha Brahmana,

> 1. Now, there are here thirty-four utterances, called expiations 1 .
>      Prag âpati, forsooth, is that sacrifice which is performed here, and from
>      which these creatures have been produced,--and in like manner are
>      they produced therefrom even to this day.
> 2. There are eight Vasus, eleven Rudras, twelve Âdityas; and these
>      two, Heaven and Earth, are the (thirty-second and) thirty-third. And
>      there are thirty-three gods, and Prag âpati is the thirty-fourth;--thus
>      he makes him (the sacrificer, or Yagña) to be Pra g âpati  : now that 
>      is, for that is immortal, and what is immortal that is. But what is mortal
>      that also is Pra g âpati; for Pragâpati is everything: thus he makes him to
>      be Pragâpati, and hence there are these thirty-four utterances, called
>      expiations.
>
> **— [Satapatha Brahmana 4:5:7:2](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe26/sbe2666.htm)**

Okay this thing is apart from your question but i include it to rigveda doesn't mention of the same type of 33 gods list but something else but like that :—

> ये देवा सो दिव्येकादशस्थ पृथिव्यामध्येकादशस्थ ।
>   अप्सुक्षितो महिनैकादशस्थ ते देवासो यज्ञमिमंजुषध्वम् ॥११॥
>
> O ye eleven gods whose home is heaven, O ye eleven who make earth your
>   dwelling, Ye who with might, eleven, live in waters,
>   accept this sacrifice, O gods, with pleasure.
>
> **—  [Rigveda 1.139.11](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01139.htm)** Translated by Ralph T. H. Griffith.
>
> 19 O ye eleven Gods whose home is heaven, O ye eleven who
>   make earth your dwelling. Ye who with might, eleven, live in
>   waters, accept this sacrifice, Ye Gods, with pleasure.
>
> **—[Yajurveda book7.19](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk07.htm)**

Although the list varies from place to place and of course Vedas describe 33 gods but no distinction that 12 adityas,8vasus etc.although in the list of adityas Indra is seen many times in vedas, puranas,Brahmanas etc. so yes **Indra is an Aditya.**

YDS above the list of adityas from two purana varies at no.8 **vishnu purana—parjanya** and **linga purana—savitra** and in whole change one name in both versions as there are 33 gods as per vedas but it does not classify them more and in diffrent-diffrent texts change the list of dities in a sequence like shatpath brahmana where unlike brihadaranyaka upnishad heaven and earth make 32 and 33 respectively so in same way in brihadaranyaka upnishad may have changed the names of adityas.

Comment: As ur all lists include Indra in Adityas..can u pls clarify how many Devas r there 32 or 33??

Comment: @YDS 33 and i think you are not confused with the last verse that's why i mentioned source so check it out if you want. :)

Comment: Just a suggestion. The source is not the URL. The source is scripture or the book you quote. E.g Linga Purana is the source, Astrojyoti is not. Hope you will remember from next time.

Comment: Thanks friend @Sarvabhouma from next time i'll keep it in mind. :) ;)

Comment: Can u pls provide interpretation of Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 3.9..Why Indra is mentioned separately to make the list of 33 Devas when it already listed 12 Adityas.. Don't u think as per the shloka i used in question, count of Devas seems only 32 as Indra is counted twice but still the shloka itself says the count is 33...

Comment: @YDS check it out. :)