# Which GOD is the true GOD?

Tags: vedas, gods

According to rig veda, the God is one. Can anyone tell who is one and only God ? Is it Shiva,Vishnu or Brahma ?

Comment: Rig Veda talks about the Brahman which is different from the Judeo-Christian concept of God

Comment: I need to know, which food is the best food. My friend is saying that Burritos are the best. However another friend of mine says that Burgers are best! Please tell me immediately. Each God is suitable to the taste of different devotee. No two people are same. Thus the One God manifests Himself in various forms to arouse the spiritual love inside the mind of the devotee! All the best!

Comment: See answers to [Is Hinduism strictly polytheistic or are the gods considered to be eventually one entity?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/117/2995)