# Is there any definition for gods?

Tags: gods, terminology

In Hinduism lot of gods available. Is there any definition for gods in Hinduism? How the gods are identified?

Comment: Probably you will get an answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/117/is-hinduism-strictly-polytheistic-or-are-the-gods-considered-to-be-eventually-on

Comment: Just wonder if you had just one way of reaching your destination or just one pair of cloth to wear daily or just one stuff to eat daily...??? It would be a chaos. Bottom line is path can be many but the main goal is same!